v_g_ctrl-g in neovim does not work
I am trying to find out the word count in selected text in neovim. For some reason, g_ctrl-g works perfectly fine in normal mode, but when I try it in visual mode after selecting some text, nothing happens. I have confirmed that the key combo has not been remapped to anything else.
I don't know how to diagnose the problem. My config is heavily modified now but I based it on https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

It should work :-) At least it works on my end. Maybe the result is overridden by some message. I would try :set cmdheight=2. What is the result of :verbose vmap g<C-g>? Does it work when you start Neovim with nvim -u NONE -i NONE or with nvim --clean?

Ah you got it. Setting the cmdheight to 2 shows it above -- VISUAL --. With nvim --clean it shows briefly instead of -- VISUAL -- without modifying the cmdheight. I assume this is because of some plugin?

@KG it's likely a plugin is the culprit (triggering a redraw or something, possibly). See How to debug my vimrc. Even with showmode on in Vim, v_g_CTRL-G stays for several seconds for me

Ok I figured out that the issue is with which-key. Upgrading it seems to have solved it.

The message could be hidden by the --VISUAL‐- message.
To avoid it you could give more room to the message area with:
set cmdheight=2


Yes that is indeed the problem. Would you know how to make it work without increasing thecmdheight?

If a plugin triggers a redraw <C-l> the message is gone forever :-|. I believe there is nothing to do :-|

Ok I figured out that the issue is with which-key. Upgrading it seems to have solved it.

Thanks for the feedback! Welcome to Vim :-)
